# Add your azure vms to your domain network

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012, window, azure

**What I am trying to do**
I have 4 VMs in azure and I want them to add them to my domain, the domain is running in home lab so no flashy equipment.

**What is required**
Except the modem provide by ISP and domain controllers, I don't have anything else. Do I require a vpn server as well on my home lab? or site to site can happen this way?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

You are right, you should deploy a site-to-site VPN then you can join your VMs to your local domain.